# RxJava - convert list and request into map

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a list of "Parent" objects and I want to get a "Child" list for each of them. I want as result a map of Parent and Child list. So the result is

```
Map<Parent, List<Child>> result = new HashMap<>();
```

My sample Parent list:

```
List<Parent> parents = new ArrayList<>();
parents.add(new Parent(1, "Parent1"));
parents.add(new Parent(2, "Parent2"));
parents.add(new Parent(3, "Parent3"));
parents.add(new Parent(4, "Parent4"));
parents.add(new Parent(5, "Parent5"));
```

I want to iterate them and ask children one by one

```
 @GET("api/childs/{parentId}")
 Observable<Response<List<Child>>> getChilds(@Path("parentId") int parentId);
```

What is the best RX structure for this?

Thank you,
Robert

Comment: Who is `Response`?

Comment: package retrofit2;

/** An HTTP response. */
public final class Response<T> {

Answer (score 5):

```
Observable.from(parents)
    .concatMap(p -> getChilds(p.getId())
        .map(Response::getValue)
        .map(children -> Pair.of(p, children)))
    .toMap(Pair::getLeft, Pair::getRight)
```

Where `Pair` is a simple wrapper of two value `left` and `right`.

Comment: p is undefined on line 4

Comment: @marchaos see line 2

Comment: Yes, but p is only available in the scope of line 2, not 4.

Comment: @marchaos you need to count brackets one by one and finally find the right bracket really in line 4 :)

Comment: oh yeah, derp :)

Answer (score 2):

The implementation that I thought of is along these lines:

Iterate through the parents, and for each try to form a `Map.Entry` with the children by using `flatMap()`. Then you can collect them into a `Map`. The code looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Parent> parents = new ArrayList<>();
    parents.add(new Parent(1, "Parent1"));
    parents.add(new Parent(2, "Parent2"));
    parents.add(new Parent(3, "Parent3"));
    parents.add(new Parent(4, "Parent4"));
    parents.add(new Parent(5, "Parent5"));

    Single<Map<Parent, List<Child>>> result = Observable.fromIterable(parents)
            .flatMap(getMapEntries())
            .toMap(keySelector(), valueSelector());
}

private static Function<Parent, Observable<Map.Entry<Parent, List<Child>>>> getMapEntries() {
    return new Function<Parent, Observable<Map.Entry<Parent, List<Child>>>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Map.Entry<Parent, List<Child>>> apply(Parent parent) throws Exception {
            return getChilds(parent.getId())
                    .map(extractResponse())
                    .map(createMapEntry(parent));
        }
    };
}

private static Function<Response<List<Child>>, List<Child>> extractResponse() {
    return new Function<Response<List<Child>>, List<Child>>() {

        @Override
        public List<Child> apply(Response<List<Child>> listResponse) throws Exception {
            return listResponse.body();
        }
    };
}

private static Function<List<Child>, Map.Entry<Parent, List<Child>>> createMapEntry(Parent parent) {
    return new Function<List<Child>, Map.Entry<Parent, List<Child>>>() {
        @Override
        public Map.Entry<Parent, List<Child>> apply(List<Child> children) throws Exception {
            return new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(parent, children);
        }
    };
}

private static Function<Map.Entry<Parent, List<Child>>, Parent> keySelector() {
    return new Function<Map.Entry<Parent, List<Child>>, Parent>() {
        @Override
        public Parent apply(Map.Entry<Parent, List<Child>> parentListEntry) throws Exception {
            return parentListEntry.getKey();
        }
    };
}

private static Function<Map.Entry<Parent, List<Child>>, List<Child>> valueSelector() {
    return new Function<Map.Entry<Parent, List<Child>>, List<Child>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Child> apply(Map.Entry<Parent, List<Child>> parentListEntry) throws Exception {
            return parentListEntry.getValue();
        }
    };
}
```

However, you should also handle errors for your `Response`. You can do it in `extractResponse()`, by throwing an exception for instance.

Btw, the plural for `child` is `children`.